# How to extract variable in actix_web example code?

Tags: rust, actix-web

Here's actix_web example code from its homepage:

```rust
use actix_web::{web, App, Responder, HttpServer};

fn index(info: web::Path<(String, u32)>) -> impl Responder {
    format!("Hello {}! id:{}", info.0, info.1)
}

fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    HttpServer::new(|| App::new().service(
        web::resource("/{name}/{id}/index.html").to(index))
    )
        .bind("127.0.0.1:8080")?
        .run()
}
```

I tried to refactor code by extracting a variable for `web::resource...` line as:

```rust
use actix_web::{web, App, HttpServer, Responder};

fn index(info: web::Path<(u32, String)>) -> impl Responder {
    format!("Hello {}! id:{}", info.1, info.0)
}

fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let route = web::resource("/{id}/{name}/index.html").to(index);
    HttpServer::new(|| App::new().service(route))
        .bind("127.0.0.1:8080")?
        .run()
}
```

But it failed to compile. Why failed? And how to extract that variable here? Thanks.

Comment: Can you please provide the compiler error you're getting?

Comment: Try adding `move` in front of your closure: `move || App::new().service (route)`

Comment: @SimonWhitehead lots of error messages, the first one is: within `[closure@src\main.rs:9:21: 9:54 route:actix_web::resource::Resource]`, the trait `std::clone::Clone` is not implemented for `actix_web::resource::Resource

Comment: @Jmb it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the service needs exclusive ownership in a multi-threaded environment. Normally you would just clone it but as you noticed, `actix_web::resource::Resource` does not implement `std::clone::Clone`. One way would be to implements this trait yourself and call clone.

A simpler way around this would be to use a closure:

```
fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let route = || web::resource("/{id}/{name}/index.html").to(index);
    HttpServer::new(move || {
        App::new().service(route())
    })
        .bind("127.0.0.1:8080")?
        .run()
}
```

You could also go with [this](https://github.com/actix/actix-web/issues/408#issuecomment-406994821) approach, which may be the reason why you want to extract the variable outside.